# Pg admin 4 - error creating any new table

Tags: sql, postgresql, syntax-error, create-table

whenever I am trying to create a new table on PgAdmin 4 tool for postgresql I am getting an error

Query: `CREATE TABLE geeks_table`

> ERROR:  syntax error at end of input
> LINE 1: CREATE TABLE geeks_table
> ^
> SQL state: 42601
> Character: 25

[image]

Comment: Please check the tutorial [in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-table.html) and compare that to your code. Especially pay attention to the first sentence: "*You can create a new table by specifying the table name, **along with all column names and their types***"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments, you need to add the data definition language (DDL) to the create statement.

The database needs to know what columns and data types are required, for example, the following DDL will create a 2 column table:

```
CREATE TABLE geeks_table (
    code        INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    title       varchar(40) NOT NULL
);
```

If you're aiming for a table without columns, this is the syntax

```
CREATE TABLE geeks_table ();
```

Comment: Thanks it answered my problem.